# Generating random numbers given required distribution and empirical sampling

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I have two sets of samplings, one distributes exponentially and the second- Bernoli (I used [scipy.stats.expon](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.expon.html) and [scipy.stats.bernoulli](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bernoulli.html#scipy.stats.bernoulli) to fit my data).

Based on these sampling, I want to create two random generators that will enable me to sample numbers from the two distributions.

What alternatives are there for doing so?

How can I find the correct parameters for creating the random generators?

Comment: `I used scipy.stats.expon and scipy.stats.bernoulli to fit my data` - do you mean `to generate my data?`. Distributions have a `.fit()` function, that you can use to get a Maximum Likelihood estimation of the parameters. After that you just sample from the distribution with the estimated parameters.

Comment: "sample from the distribution with the estimated parameters" - that is exactly where I'm blocked. Is there any tutotial\code snipet you can refer to that explains how to use this estimated parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `rvs` method to generate a sample using the estimated parameters.  For example, suppose `x` holds my initial data.

```
In [56]: x
Out[56]: 
array([ 0.366,  0.235,  0.286,  0.84 ,  0.073,  0.108,  0.156,  0.029,
        0.11 ,  0.122,  0.227,  0.148,  0.095,  0.233,  0.317,  0.027])
```

Use `scipy.stats.expon` to fit the expononential distribution to this data.  I assume we are interested in the usual case where the location parameter is 0, so I use `floc=0` in the `fit` call.

```
In [57]: from scipy.stats import expon

In [58]: loc, scale = expon.fit(x, floc=0)

In [59]: scale
Out[59]: 0.21076203455218898
```

Now use those parameters to generate a random sample.

```
In [60]: sample = expon.rvs(loc=0, scale=scale, size=8)

In [61]: sample
Out[61]: 
array([ 0.21576877,  0.23415911,  0.6547364 ,  0.44424148,  0.07870868,
        0.10415167,  0.12905163,  0.23428833])
```