# What is the parameter that one obtains with stats.expon.fit()?

Tags: scipy, statistics

The scipy.stats.expon.fit(data) function is supposed to fit data to the equation

```html
<a href="https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=$\lambda&space;e^{-\lambda&space;x}$" target="_blank"><img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?$\lambda&space;e^{-\lambda&space;x}$" title="$\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$" /></a>
```

However, sometimes the equation is expressed as

```html
<a href="https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}" target="_blank"><img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}" title="\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}" /></a>
```

I revised the documentation in scipy, but I am not sure if the method returns lambda or beta. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scipy.stats.expon` has two parameters, the location `loc` and the scale  `scale`.  (In fact, *all* the univariate continuous distributions in SciPy include these two parameters.)  Neither of the two versions that you show include the location parameter `loc`.  You can think of them as having fixed `loc=0`; when you use the `fit` method, you can achieve this by using the argument `floc=0`.  See [Generating random numbers given required distribution and empirical sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789408/generating-random-numbers-given-required-distribution-and-empirical-sampling/36795076#36795076) for an example.

SciPy's `scale` corresponds to β in your second version of the distribution, or 1/λ in the first version.